# Print using javascript for more than 1 printers

Tags: php, javascript, printing

I want to print 2 kind of documents on 2 different printers. I use "Always print silent" on firefox so the print window doesn't show up on every print. But now I want 2 different prints I can not use this option and I really don't want the print window to show up. Any idea how I can do this like changing the default printer using javascript or php ( I don't think php can help me here because printer is client side ) or something else.
thanx in advance

Comment: I upvoted the question out of curiosity, because I don't think it can be done...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to control this with PHP or Javascript.

Your best option would be to write a Firefox plugin to do it for you.

Comment: @brasofilo this question is for 5 years ago. I have no idea how I solved it.

Comment: PHP has the ability to talk to printers, but such a feat requires them on the same network or a cloud API.  If interested in some techniques other have used (locally installed apps, APIs, etc) please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28783269/3196753

Answer (score 0):

Javascript and/or PHP cannot change browser or computer settings.