# Alternative to Jzebra/QZ Java Raw Print Plugin after NPAPI being dropped on Chrome Browser

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, printing

We all know that NPAPI will be completely removed from Chrome in a few months.

What would be an alternative to the Jzebra/QZ Java plugin that makes raw printing (sending raw ESC/P commands) to POS printers?

Is there a Chrome API (HTML5 and Javascript) that will be able to replace the communication between the browser and the locally installed POS printers in USB or Ethernet?

Answer (score 18):

> Is there a Chrome API (HTML5 and Javascript) that will be able to replace the communication between the browser and the locally installed POS printers in USB or Ethernet?

**Update:** A pure HTML5 solution exists for USB devices, but examples are currently hard to find and browser adoption has been slow:

- [WebUSB](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web) USB devices only, select browsers.

In regards to HTML5 and JavaScript, since the removal of NPAPI, the solution tends to involve WebSocket to localhost, or cloud-enabled printers.

This HTTP/WebSockets design is used by:

- Zebra [Link-OS](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/link-os-sdk.html) and [Cloud Connect](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/cloud-connect.html) (for label printing, etc)
- Epson [ePOS-Device](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_epos_device_js_en/index.php?content_id=139) (for receipts, display, barcode scanner)
- Dymo [JavaScript Framework 2.0](http://developers.dymo.com/2015/09/24/dymo-label-framework-javascript-library-2-0-open-beta-2/) (for label printing, etc)
- [PrintNode](https://www.printnode.com/)
- [Google Cloud Print](https://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/) (Slated for retirement Dec 2020)
- [Neodynamic TLClient Print](https://www.neodynamic.com/downloads/tlclientprint/) (.NET-based for thermal printers)
- [QZ Tray software](https://qz.io/download) (the successor to "JZebra/QZ-Print", labels, receipts, *anything raw*, PDFs, HTML, USB Scales, USB barcode readers, serial devices)

In regards to Point-Of-Sale specific printing, I have been unable to locate a ready solution that meets these needs (pure HTML5 and JavaScript, widely adopted), so either a Desktop-installed middle-ware or a server-side middle-ware is currently the way to achieve what you are describing.

Full disclaimer, we're the authors of QZ Tray.

Comment: Thanks so much for this list, I've been looking for a reliable solution to print labels from a web client, going to give QZ Tray a shot.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [PrintNode](https://www.printnode.com) which has a simple desktop client and json API.  It's really quick and has lots of libs: https://github.com/PrintNode/

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with [Epson's ePOS-Print JavaScript SDK](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_epos_device_js_en/index.php?content_id=139). It is Epson specific and does require a network interface card that supports ePOS (UB-E04/R04).

Comment: This technically answers the question because it is both HTML5 and JavaScript.  I'm up-voting but also adding it to the listing above.