# PDF printing labels on Zebra printer using Google Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, label, zebra-printers, pdfviewer

I created an application in ASPX.NET to issue tags for the Zebra TPL-2844 printer, the application usually works in Internet Explorer and Firefox, however for some problem in Google Chrome the label image is interpreted wrong by the Chrome preview.

Is there any way to open with a different PDF interpreter that runs on Google Chrome to print stickers on Zebra?

I need help!

Comment: If you're ok bypassing the browser's printing entirely, there are some solutions that can do that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28783269/3196753

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome print preview, you need to uncheck "Header and footers", and set all margin to 0.

You can use this guide: [Setting-Up-Chrome-For-Windows-To-Print](https://websitesupport.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205959070-Setting-Up-Chrome-For-Windows-To-Print-From-The-Rain-Point-Of-Sale)